# Custom Export SVF from AutoCAD in Design Automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-designautomation

I am attempting to create a custom SVF export process using AutoCAD and Design Automation.

I've attempted the following two approaches:

1. Create a custom plugin (app bundle) for AutoCAD that leverages the export commands: "prepareforpropertyextraction", "publishtosvf" etc.
2. Create a custom activity that uses the Autodesk provided shared app bundle: "AutoCAD.Publish2View22+prod"

With approach #1 the result is "Unknown command" when attempting to execute the export commands.

With approach #2 I create a custom activity that uses the "AutoCAD.Publish2View22+prod" app bundle. Once again the result is "Unknown command" when the script executes the export commands. Here is my activity:

```
{
    "commandLine": [
        "$(engine.path)\\accoreconsole.exe /al \"$(appbundles[Publish2View22].path)\" /i \"$(args[HostDwg].path)\" /s \"$(settings[script].path)\""
    ],
    "parameters": {
        "HostDwg": {
            "verb": "get",
            "description": "AutoCAD file to process",
            "required": true,
            "localName": "$(HostDwg)"
        },
        "Result": {
            "zip": true,
            "verb": "post",
            "description": "Conversion Results",
            "required": true,
            "localName": "result"
        }
    },
    "id": "abc123.GTDWGConverter+alpha",
    "engine": "Autodesk.AutoCAD+24",
    "appbundles": [
        "AutoCAD.Publish2View22+prod",
        "abc123.GTDWGConverter+alpha"
    ],
    "settings": {
        "script": {
            "value": "(command \"_3DDWFPREC\" \"4\")\n(command \"_prepareforpropertyextraction\" \"index.json\")\n(command \"_indexextractor\" \"index.json\")\n(command \"_publishtosvf\" \"./output/result.svf\")\n(command \"_createbubblepackage\" \"./output\" \"./result\" \"\" \"\")\n"
        }
    },
    "description": "Gametime Component Converter",
    "version": 13
}
```

Here is the result of the running the activity:

```
[05/05/2023 23:34:37] Job information:
"CommandLine":[
  "$(engine.path)\\accoreconsole.exe /al \"$(appbundles[Publish2View22].path)\" /i \"$(args[HostDwg].path)\" /s \"$(settings[script].path)\""
]
"Settings":{
  "script": {
    "value": "(command \"3DDWFPREC\" \"1\")\n(command \"_prepareforpropertyextraction\" \"index.json\")\n(command \"_indexextractor\" \"index.json\")\n(command \"_publishtosvf\" \"./output/result.svf\")\n(command \"_createbubblepackage\" \"./output\" \"./result\" \"\" \"\")\n"
  },
  "dasOpenNetwork": {
    "value": "true",
    "isEnvironmentVariable": true
  }
}
"Id":"b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz"
"ActivityId":"abc123.GTConverter+alpha"
"Engine.Id":"Autodesk.AutoCAD_24!32"
"Apps": [
"App.Id":"AutoCAD.Publish2View22!1"
]
"BoundArguments":{
  "HostDwg": {
    "localName": "$(HostDwg)",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:xtswzYVOXmxMvPRuNOYvFr/iON0="
  },
  "Result": {
    "zip": true,
    "localName": "result",
    "url": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/Masked:qieD6b4PZfBMSzPW3QqM2PUtmbU=",
    "verb": "put"
  },
  "onProgress": {
    "ondemand": true,
    "url": "https://wlnr5sjl3a.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/Masked:UK/Z3b5X3xUWxXiH6C9r9i9UlRU=",
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "x-das-authorize": "awssigv4(us-east-1)",
      "x-ads-token-data": "{\"access_token\":{\"client_id\":\"abc123\"},\"scope\":\"code:all\",\"expires_in\":3589,\"client_id\":\"abc123\"}",
      "x-ads-gateway-secret": "Masked:F6VCvje5cIP0zOGCxgARjmSopQI="
    },
    "verb": "put"
  }
}
"Quotas":{
  "limitProcessingTimeSec": 100,
  "limitTotalUncompressedAppsSizeInMB": 500
}
[05/05/2023 23:34:37] Folder "T:\Aces\Jobs\b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz\result" has been created.
[05/05/2023 23:34:37] Starting work item b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz
[05/05/2023 23:34:37] Start download phase.
[05/05/2023 23:34:37] Start downloading input: verb - 'GET', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/00000000-d65f-42a1-b3f3-ae574b80eedc?region=US'
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] End downloading file. Source=https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/00000000-d65f-42a1-b3f3-ae574b80eedc?region=US,LocalFile=T:\Aces\Jobs\b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz\1abb77116c2d4e978fc7cd19f05c646a.dwg,BytesDownloaded=1946093,Duration=328ms
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] End download phase successfully.
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] Start preparing script and command line parameters.
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] Command line: [ /al "T:\Aces\Applications\4ee88136735a0aac6c36a5467191d096.AutoCAD.Publish2View22[1].package" /i "T:\Aces\Jobs\b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz\1abb77116c2d4e978fc7cd19f05c646a.dwg" /s "T:\Aces\Jobs\b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz\setting_script.scr"]
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] End preparing script and command line parameters.
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] Start script phase.
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] Start AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump.
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] Redirect stdout (file: T:\Aces\Jobs\b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz\tmp\accc8162).
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] AcCoreConsole: StdOutConsoleMode: processed-output: disabled,auto
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] AutoCAD Core Engine Console - Copyright 2020 Autodesk, Inc.  All rights reserved. (R.47.Z.170)
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] Execution Path:
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] T:\Aces\AcesRoot\24.0\coreEngine\Exe\accoreconsole.exe
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] Current Directory: T:\Aces\Jobs\b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] Isolating to regkey=HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\AppDataLow\Software\Autodesk\CoreUser\WorkItem_b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz, userDataFolder=T:\Aces\Jobs\b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz\userdata.
[05/05/2023 23:34:38] Version Number: R.47.Z.170 (UNICODE)
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Loading Mechanical modules.....
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Loader application completed
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Loading Modeler DLLs.
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Regenerating model.
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Auditing Mechanical Data...
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Number of errors found: 2    Number of errors fixed: 1
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Auditing Mechanical Data complete.
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] AutoCAD menu utilities loaded.
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Command:
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Command:
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Command:
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Command: (command "3DDWFPREC" "1")
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] 3DDWFPREC
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Enter new value for 3DDWFPREC <2>: 1
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Command: nil
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Command: (command "_prepareforpropertyextraction" "index.json")
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] _prepareforpropertyextraction Unknown command "PREPAREFORPROPERTYEXTRACTION".  Press F1 for help.
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Command: index.json Unknown command "JSON".  Press F1 for help.
[05/05/2023 23:34:39] Command: nil
[05/05/2023 23:34:40] End AutoCAD Core Engine standard output dump.
[05/05/2023 23:34:40] Error: AutoCAD Core Console output contains error(s).
[05/05/2023 23:34:40] End script phase.
[05/05/2023 23:34:40] Start upload phase.
[05/05/2023 23:34:40] Zipping directory T:\Aces\Jobs\b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz\result as T:\Aces\Jobs\b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz\result.zip.
[05/05/2023 23:34:40] Uploading 'T:\Aces\Jobs\b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz\result.zip': verb - 'PUT', url - 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/signedresources/00000000-d1a1-48f4-a98a-b387e494ca88?region=US'
[05/05/2023 23:34:40] End upload phase successfully.
[05/05/2023 23:34:40] Job finished with result Succeeded
[05/05/2023 23:34:40] Job Status:
{
  "status": "success",
  "reportUrl": "https://dasprod-store.s3.amazonaws.com/workItem/abc123/b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz/report.txt?X-Amz-Expires=4620&X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEAYaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJGMEQCICLotPjsH3b1wRIt%2FWGnjVGltqxOO1g5EV7AOyZCZR11AiBVQAU98SM%2BcjxyMmBQFKGJFsUqg15cOEprhrbAR1rJoyqAAwgfEAMaDDIyMDQ3MzE1MjMxMCIMEMbUB%2BP6qSRnOA9DKt0C3iD8YE51GgBTUMCb2qUCDynXQ3ss8yAsGG3vmdCI%2FFVRmSPWOM44wg6ETvd5a55BS31zQX%2FdiE%2FR8cPl5BlM3lDH68QfyZubRI6EfU65Kss1iGDQml5UvXM4zaAypJIW%2B1hj%2Bp0tV0lAmhxBYnR%2Fuqrxbmmze6zw9foo5l7l1camyaN3IfG9OQOLu6LHwhQ1XJ5qrm0beWrC1dx8GehKHIWwiizrOpHefRhYA9HbwPpZ47zHArkdBoPQ%2Fp3JYj5nyUiDtZQq7xu2w9YK%2FTbo3uB5JlN6sN%2BuOOw2DS%2Fl4g7xxbvY4Y9471d0sq3j3uYyRGLXP4kKxpa7soPEhQl3GN2Mi9VGdRYna3rVxw9umE8P4jIM32A3f8nmjZMk5%2Bgpci%2BmZSpFnDxFZfoYooOByP2QfkM7vd9DCF2X86puJU3nD2Xy5TYGmwDx8nPKr%2BYOX1Js%2BptL8ZuEaaDS0DDH%2BdWiBjqfAbb4xOrk%2BgCUCA3QGoorAEuN5mdCQUEnyr2%2B6jl5yyyLOuevhQVN0qR8sgF%2FsHEl%2F7foWNAoiTno7%2BvyHuQaJnXap%2B5JMy8z8C%2FeBEyM3WL9pNa9EMih0DxGOtT0%2BZennhqggcTz%2BcU69bPjV3dV5SnwJ%2Bm2X5ueSTAGQIJHLePchycXHx2hZhu2ES2GBg042xa0rK%2FgFDw%2F78nB%2BZHe2g%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Credential=ASIATGVJZKM3CK7PRAD2/20230505/us-east-1/s3/aws4_request&X-Amz-Date=20230505T233437Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Signature=468f2dc2b50e2b45ec255140e027117ec592af1b559bfd1e65376067801793d6",
  "stats": {
    "timeQueued": "2023-05-05T23:34:37.5500325Z",
    "timeDownloadStarted": "2023-05-05T23:34:37.6426294Z",
    "timeInstructionsStarted": "2023-05-05T23:34:38.0470725Z",
    "timeInstructionsEnded": "2023-05-05T23:34:40.511409Z",
    "timeUploadEnded": "2023-05-05T23:34:40.7594337Z",
    "bytesDownloaded": 1946093,
    "bytesUploaded": 22
  },
  "id": "b0cfe7a3bfcd45c7bc4dd8134f6f8xyz"
}
```

My assumptions:

1. The custom export commands are defined in the "Publish2View22" app bundle.
2. The "Publish2View22" app bundle will not load in activities with currently supported engine versions i.e. 24+

Are my assumptions correct? If so, how can we accomplish our goal of creating a custom activity that leverages the AutoCAD custom SVF export functionality through Design Automation?

Comment: It looks like we don't have Publish2View24_1 or Publish2View24_2..